# jupyter notebook - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: cmd.exe, localhost, jupyter-notebook

I've been, stuck with this, issue, from many hours, recently instlled jupyter, and its not laucing correctly, it doesnt open chrome - default browser automatically either..

```
To access the server, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/MLaptop/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-14040-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/tree?token=0d17ed3ad75657d1a6780ea9ff00e2bce22213dbcb0b5f14
    http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=0d17ed3ad75657d1a6780ea9ff00e2bce22213dbcb0b5f14
```

I have tried, entering each url, in browser filed, all gives same error, ERR_Refused_to-connect...
now, how to do resolve this,.. based on google search results, so far, I have tried

tried to disable firewall- Windows Firewall,-- same error > tried uninstall jupyter- reinstall - restart system, - same error

- How do I check, if jupyter notebook- server did start at 8888 port
- any way to check if, port 8888 is being used by some other app
- are there any other way to run jupyter notebook- like changing port
  jupyter uses, or any other ways, I can launch jupyter and work on it
- any way to check, if its jupyter specific problem, Or something wrong
  with my local-host and ports- or in browser - like run something to make sure, that local-host etc are fine..

[Log-Link](https://justpaste.it/a9c40) < If it helps

ThankYou